# (ANSI) SQL QUERY FOR AGGREGATED DATA

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

PROBLEM

SALES_TABLE has 3 columns:  SALES_DIVISION, STATE, AND SALES_AMT

The specs are:

1. create a column called REGION with valid values 'EASTERN', 'CENTRAL', 'PACIFIC' or NULL by default:

- set to EASTERN if state = NY or MA
- set to CENTRAL if state = IL or TX
- set to PACIFIC if state = CA, OR, or WA

2. we want to group the data by SALES_DIVISION, REGION, and STATE
3. create columns EAST, CENTRAL, and PAC with values of 1 or 0:

- if the aggregated SALES_AMT > 0  and REGION = EASTERN then set column EAST to 1 else 0
- if the aggregated SALES_AMT > 0  and REGION = CENTRAL then set column CENTRAL to 1  else 0
- if the aggregated SALES_AMT > 0  and REGION = PACIFIC then set column PACIFIC to 1 else 0

Below is the query that I built from the sales table, grouping the data by SALES_DIVISION, REGION, and STATE:

[image]

The above query  produces something like this:

| SALES_DIVISON | REGION | STATE | EAST | CENTRAL | PAC | EAST_CENTRAL | CENTRAL_PACIFIC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DIV_01 | EASTERN | NY | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| DIV_01 | EASTERN | MA | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| DIV_01 | CENTRAL | TX | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| DIV_02 | PACIFIC | CA | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| DIV_03 | CENTRAL | TX | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| DIV_03 | PACIFIC | WA | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

HOWEVER, the end user wants us to provide an AGGREGATED RESULT as follows:

| SALES_DIVISON | REGION | STATE | EAST | CENTRAL | PAC | EAST_CENTRAL | CENTRAL_PACIFIC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DIV_01 | - | - | 1 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| DIV_02 | - | - | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| DIV_03 | - | - | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

SPECIFICATIONS for the AGGREGATED RESULT:

1. leave the REGION and STATE as blank
2. even though we say "aggregate" - the EAST , CENTRAL, AND PAC values will STILL remain 0 or 1.  So in the case of "DIV_01", which has two EASTERN states,   we want the EAST column to still show 1 instead of 2 in the AGGREGATED RESULT.
3. The EAST_CENTRAL and CENTRAL_PACIFIC values should be the aggregate of the query result #1. In the case of "DIV_01" where we have two EASTERN regions - though the EAST column shows  only 1 (as required by SPEC #1), the EAST_CENTRAL column value  should show value of 3  because we have 2 eastern states plus 1 central state.

QUESTION: how do I create a SELECT statement to get the aggregated result?  Would it be possible to do a SELECT statement out of the SELECT -GROUP BY statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a CTE (Common Table Expression) based on your first query, and then write derivative queries off of that.

```
WITH sales_cte as (your_select_query_here)

select sales_division, NULL as State, NULL as Region, sum(East), sum(Central), sum(Pac), sum(East_Central), sum(Central_Pacific)
from sales_cte
group by sales_division;
```

Comment: t works, but I just need to create new columns (with suffix of _AGG) for the aggregated output for the EAST,  CENTRAL, and PAC as follows:   “CASE WHEN SUM(East)  > 0 THEN 1ELSE 0 END AS EAST_AGG” and do the same thing for CENTRAL_AGG and PAC_AGG.